# VPN slows down whole internet connection

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I used to connect to a home server through a private VPN and I used it just to access phpMyAdmin and the MySQL database (from my application). When connected to the VPN, my internet speed was not changed at all, everything was alright.

I reinstalled my Ubuntu and set up the VPN connection again and now when I connect to the VPN, the net speed becomes suuuper slow. Can't open any page. I don't get timeouts, though, so I guess everything gets redirected through the VPN.

I am really not a networks guy, so I have no clue what to dig into. Any suggestions?

Outputs from `route -n`...

NOT connected to VPN:
[image]

Connected to VPN:
[image]

After calling the commands:

```
sudo ip route del default via 192.168.2.5
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
```

now the internet connection is not slowed down, but I cannot access the server to which I am connecting through the VPN. Isn't that because I am deleting the IP somehow? Here's a screenshot of the `route -n` output:
[image]

P.S. the server IP changes between `.5`, `.9` and `.13`.

Comment: can you put output from command `route -n` when vpn is connected and when is not?

Comment: It seems like you are routing the whole traffic through the VPN instead of only your home net.

Try to setup your vpn in a way, that only 192.168.1.0/24 (replace with your home network) is routed through the vpn.

Comment: @2707974, I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your routing table say that after connecting to `vpn` change default gw from `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.2.9` aka route all traffic through `tun0` interface.

To avoid this you can add following

Create script for `tun0` interface

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

put in script this

```
    # Check for specific interface if desired
    [ "$IFACE" != "tun0" ] || exit 0
    # trigger vpn connection
    ip route del default via 192.168.2.9
    ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
```

Save and exit.

Make script called `script` with execute permissions 755

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

This script will be triggered after `tun0` interface go up and simple make `wlan0` default interface for internet traffic.

Or, you can, after establishing a vpn connection in terminal run this commands,

First remove default gw the add new

```
sudo ip route del default via 192.168.2.9
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
```

but this is temporary and must be done every time when connect to `vpn`

Or, based on you setup, in `/etc/network/interfaces` in the part of config a `tun0` interface add command

Example:

```
iface tun0 inet static
      --omited some config--

      address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
      pointopoint xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
      netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
      up route add -net ..
      --omited some config--

      #change default gw
      up ip route del default via 192.168.2.9
      up ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
```

All of this way of configuration will back default route to `wlan0` interface
after `vpn` connection.

Comment: the first option was not working, so I tried the second one (which is the temporary one) and I got an error, directly in the terminal: `Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "192.168.1.1" is a garbage.` I will investigate this now, but if you have the solution before me - let me know.

Comment: For now try only temporary solution again. I have typo mistake. One `Space` more between default and 192....

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the typo already the first time when I tried it. :) But it doesn't work still...

Comment: I edited answer, try.

Comment: Yeah, now the internet connection is not slowed down, but I cannot access the server to which I am connecting through the VPN. Isn't that because I am deleting the IP somehow?

Comment: On witch ip is server?

Comment: And what say `route -n` about that ip?

Comment: I updated my question, with a screenshot :)

Comment: On witch ip is server? You can add more route to specific ip `sudo ip route add 192.168.2.xxx/32 dev tun0` or range `sudo ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev tun0`